# What are free floater code?

Tags: java

which code can be considered free floaters ? I am java beginner and I want to know how can I figure out free floater code.

```
public class Ocz2{

//Ocz2 obj = new Ocz2();

int a[] ;

a=new int[3];

}
```

In the above code, I am not able to figure out why it is throwing error on line 3. same declaration(line 3 & 4) doesn't throw any error inside method.
But from error and google search I got to know it is because free floater code.
Kindly help.

Comment: Did you translate this from another language? I'm not familiar with the term "free floater code".

Comment: I think they are referring to the fact that the code isn't embedded in a "project" or has a main function etc, but rather just some "free floating" code. For OP - I think it's just a figure of speech. It's not something formally defined or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your line

```
a=new int[3];
```

Is free floater as it doesn't belong to a block, constructor or a function. Java doesn't allow free floating code.

Wrap your line in any block, constructor or in a function.

Comment: So if it is included inside block then it would not be considered floating code ride right ? and also it should be included inside block because array declaration is in one line and initalization in the other line and they both have connection.So for this reason does it make it to be called floating code ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your class do not have any function.
Therefore , the correct way would be using main function.

```
public class Ocz2{
public static void main(String args[]){
//Ocz2 obj = new Ocz2();
int a[] ;
 a=new int[3];
  }
 }
```